# Issue with updating audio current time when clicking on progress bar

Tags: javascript, html, laravel

I have an audio player with a progress bar, and I want to update the current time of the audio when the user clicks on the progress bar. I have the following code snippet:

```
document.querySelector('.range').addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    const newWidth = (event.pageX - progressBar.offsetLeft) / progressBar.parentElement.offsetWidth * 100;
    progressBar.style.width = newWidth + '%';

    // Calculate the new time based on the clicked position
    let newTime = (newWidth / 100) * audio_Element.duration;
    console.log(newTime); // returns the correct time

    audio_Element.currentTime = newTime;
});
```

However, when I click on the progress bar, the audio starts from the beginning instead of setting the new time.

newTime ruturn this value when i click on the bar in consol:
[image]

Here is the HTML for the audio element:

```
<audio class="audio" src="{{ url('/storage/' . $song->path) }}"></audio>
```

Comment: The computed percentage is the right one?

Comment: Thanks for your Reply but I didn't understand.

Comment: Have you ensured that `newWidth` is always between 0 and 100?

Comment: I personally use the element's bounding rect as well as the mouse event's position to compute it. `(e.x - rect.left) / rect.width * 100`

Comment: yes i have confirm that i have also give new time static like `audio_Element.currentTime = 20`

Comment: Could you produce an example that reproduces the issue please?

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if the time value you are trying to seek to is within the range of the buffer.  You can check the `seekable` time range and ensure your new time value is within that range.
[HTMLMediaElement/seekable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/seekable)

Or you can check what time range is buffered by looking at the `buffered` attribute.
[HTMLMediaElement/buffered](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/buffered)

Comment: Hi Wandering Code! Thank you for your reply . i checked buffered it showing length 1!

Comment: The media has a known duration, so seekable and buffered are irrelevant in this context

Comment: its about 2 days i am trying to find a solution but i don't found any solution .
when ever I try to update the current time it become 0 no matter what value I assign

Comment: I initially thought the time value you were using was invalid so it was defaulting to 0.  I didn't notice the console output you posted that shows seemingly valid numbers.  So far I'm not able to recreate the issue.  Can you create a jsfiddle that causes this behavior?